# What architectural perspectives do you consider as part of your overall software design?

Tags: architecture

When someone uses the term XXX architecture I tend to cringe.  It often indicates that there's another architectural discipline or perspective that I'm probably not considering.  What perspectives of architecture are you considering and do you have any good resources for information on them?

I hope this helps others who are working their way through the architecture profession.

- Survivability
- Performance Management
- Operational Monitoring & Management
- Service Orientation
- TOGAF defines a number of quality of service attributes

Sorry for the edit, but your answers were spot on and I think the question needed to be refined.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include my bottom-up (requirements) viewpoint as well as my original top-down (organisation) viewpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecture and architectural decisions are primarily about the "non-functional" requirements of a system; *pace* RoadWarrier, but each of the things he mentions are consequences of the architectural decisions more than independent in and of themselves.  (Proof: what leads to a particular choice in any of those domains?  It's always the need to satisfy some nonfunctional requirement.)

With that in mind, it's a two part issue.  First, you need to decide what NFRs are important. preferably by stating them with some specificity using a rigorous method, eg, don't just say "highly available", say "the system must be available (MTTF/(MTTF+MTTR)) 99.99 percent, with the longest single duration outage being 4 minutes."

Second, you need to consider what views will help you to design to satisfy these requirements *and justify your decisions*.  Depending on the stringency of your requirements, this may be anything from a white board block diagram to a formal simulation study.

In a *business* domain, say in an IT system available over a web interface, you might, for example, want:

- reliability (MMTF)
- availability (MTTF/(MTTF+MTTR))
- scaleability (system must be able to add 10 pct capacity within 72 hours at X cost)
- capacity (system must sustain 1 million active users)
- throughput (system must process 100 transactions per second mean with σ=2.5 tps)
- response time (under test load user must receive full page in ≤ 2 seconds)
- security (metrics here is a topic for a while article in itself)

You should also, if you're specifying the performance etc characteristics, describe the *workload*, ie, the size of a user's data, the arrival rate of web requests, etc.

Comment: Great answer Charlie.  I realize questions like these are likely to solicit answers that are well beyond the space we're allotted, but it's a great starting point.  Do you have any resources you regularly review when reviewing your architecture for completeness?

Comment: No, but I'm writing a book ;-)

Comment: Charlie, your answer is from the bottom-up (requirements) viewpoint, whilst my answer is from the top-down (organisation) viewpoint. Of course, architects need both viewpoints.

Answer (score 0):

- testability
- scalability
- fault-tolerance
- performance degradation (gracefully, one hopes)
- upgradability (hardware and software)

BTW these are all reasons why I like enterprise service busses (ESBs)!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: As the question has changed in emphasis, I've edited my answer as follows.

**Architecture** and **architect** are heavily-overloaded terms. To start, you need to specify whether you're talking about a software company (where software is the product/service) or a line-of-business company (where software supports the product/service).

There is also the top-down view of architecture (what matters from the organisation viewpoint) versus the bottom-up view (what matters from the project requirements viewpoint).

In a large line-of-business company, architecture from the top-down (organisation) viewpoint is normally partitioned something like this:

- [Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_architecture) architecture, sometimes called business architecture. For example, understanding commodities trading processes and the associated IT systems.
- [Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_architecture) architecture. For example, understanding descriptions of data in storage and data in motion; descriptions of data stores, data groups and data items; and mappings of those data artifacts to data qualities, applications, and locations.
- [Technical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_architecture) architecture. For example, understanding the structure and behaviour of the technology infrastructure of an enterprise, solution or system.

My architecture areas from the bottom-up (requirements) viewpoint look something like this:

- Correct use of middleware - loose coupling, fault tolerance, target-specific transforms, killing point-to-point, etc.
- Identifying and engineering-out as many reconciliations as possible.
- Identifying and engineering-out as much dual-keying as possible.
- Identifying and engineering-out as many manual processes as possible.
- Identifying and engineering-out any end-user computing solutions - e.g. Access databases, Excel spreadsheets.
- Identifying and engineering-out any end-user editing of "the answer" - taking information after all work is completed, and then editing it.
- Investigating complete data lifecycle: who owns it, who enriches it, who distributes it, single version of the truth, removing reconciliations.
- Identifying performance and scalability metrics, testing risky areas against multiple data profiles.
- Identifying real-time versus batch processes and interfaces, and eliminating batch dependencies wherever feasible.
- Consolidation to single platform where possible, and single versus multiple instances.
- Ability to handle new vanilla business quickly, and new complex business within reasonable timescales.
- Identification of a clear support model, especially across regions where necessary.
- State maintenance and recovery - how well every-day processing and interface failures can be recovered.
- BCP/DR requirements and capabilities, general fault tolerance, WAN dependencies.
- Where can project risk be reduced?
- Security, end-user and developer access, ring of steel around production.
- What MI reporting facilities are in place?
- Emphasising simplicity as much as possible, system de-commissioning.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more about the overloading of the term.  I think far too often it leads to unclear or misalignment.  As for structure, this is really line of business.  If you look at an EA framework like zachman, it captures all 3 of the architectures you've outlined.